# drop index indexname is not working fine when i try to use this query in mysql browser

Tags: mysql

I get an error when i try to `drop` my index, or when I try to view my index using this kind of query `SHOW INDEX` or `DROP INDEX <INDEXNAME>`.

The error message is:

```
mysqlserver version for right syntax to use near at line 1"".
```

Comment: Your edit was invalid @AbdulManaf, so I have rolled it back. Please do not attempt to correct another user's English grammar until you have a firm grasp of the language yourself... which you clearly do *not* yet have.

Comment: And why don't you just look at mysql documents?

Comment: Thank you i got answer from abdulmanaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For seeing indexes**

```
show index from myTable;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| myTable |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTable |          1 | title    |            1 | title       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| myTable |          1 | price    |            1 | price       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**For Dropping index**

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP INDEX INDEX_NAME;
```

**Example**

```
show create table myTable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: myTable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `price` (`price`),
  KEY `idx_price_title` (`price`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I need to drop index **idx_price_title**

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP INDEX idx_price_title;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Check whether or not the index exists

```
show create table myTable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: myTable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i am new to this stack overflow..its just amazing lot of peoples are here to help me thank you so much...@abdul manaf

Comment: You can Right tick the answer!!

Comment: could u tell me what are all facilities behind this stackoverflow especially for conversation with technical people...@ abdul manaf